# What does *1.0 do in this code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, primes

Here is a code for checking if a number is prime or not :

```
bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    if(num<=1)
        return false;
    if(num==2)
        return true;
    if(num%2==0)
        return false;
    int sRoot = sqrt(num*1.0);
    for(int i=3; i<=sRoot; i+=2)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

What does the expression " num*1.0 " mean ?

Comment: You probably get an ambiguous overload compiler error without it.

Comment: Effectively, it casts the `int` to a `double`. Not the clearest way, in my opinion. Just `static_cast<double>` it.

Comment: @GManNickG - it **converts** the `int` to a `double`. There is no cast in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplying by `1.0` forces the `num` into a `double`. You can do the same with an explicit cast.

Comment: @KhoderSarm the compiler down-concerts the result to an `int`, truncating the fractional part.

Comment: @KhoderSarm `sqrt` takes a double and rerturns a double. `* 1.0` is casting the argument as a double, this has nothing to do with the return type. Since `sRoot` is an int, the return value of `sqrt` will be cast to an int from a double.

Comment: @Khoder A floating point value can be implicitly converted to an integer value by truncating the fractional part. A compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun - the return value will be **converted**. A **cast** is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, I keep forgetting about that distinction.

Answer (score 3):

it is doing num x 1.0 so if num is 5 it is 5 x 1.0
the sqrt() method takes double as its parameter and would take 5.0

Answer (score 3):

In `num*1.0`, `num` is promoted to `double` first, so the result is a `double` and then pass to `double sqrt(double)`. Otherwise, you may need to use `sqrt(static_cast<double>(num))`.

Generally, you don't need the cast because there is **an implicit cast** from `int` to `double`. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178618/sqrt-taking-int-in-c).