# C: datatypes. sqrt function working with int why?

Tags: c, types

I am beginner in C, started after JavaScript and cannot get used to these types.

Okay math.h's sqrt function should work with doubles and as far as I understand it, in C you cannot pass the wrong types as parameters.

But when I go:

```
int b = sqrt(1234); //it works
```

so does

```
float b = sqrt(1234); // it works
int b = sqrt(1234.22) // it works
```

Why are all these working? What does the process look like here?

My guess is: The parameters of sqrt are automatically converted to double regardless of what I pass,
and the result double is converted to int if the variable I am assigning to is type int.

Then two questions?

1) why do I get an error with other functions if I pass the wrong type but not with sqrt?
2) if we can just convert int to float like this

```
 float b = 123.44
 int a = b;
```

why do we need this?

```
 float b = 123.44
 int a = (int) b;
```

Comment: When you send it as parameter you actually create a variable of the type of parameter and the variable passed is cast to the type of the parameter.

Comment: your guess is correct. 1) an example please, 2) you don't need it: http://ideone.com/x3AQqt

Comment: "why do I get an error with other functions if I pass the wrong type but not with sqrt" - that's not a general thing; some implicit conversions are possible, some are not. 2. "why do we need this?" - what lead you to believe that you need that? **You don't.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqrt() of int type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178618/sqrt-of-int-type-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are all these [two initializations] work?

The first initialization `float b = sqrt(1234)` works because the language "upcasts" the integer literal `1234` to `double` before calling `sqrt`, and then converting the result to `float`.

The second initialization `int b = sqrt(1234.22)` works for the same reason, except this time the compiler does not have to upcast `1234.22` literal before the call, because it is already of type `double`.

This is  discussed in C99 standard:

> 6.3.1.4.1: When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded.
>
> 6.7.8.11: The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that of the expression **(after conversion)** (emphasis added).

-

> why do we need this [cast `int a = (int) b;`]?

You may insert a cast for readability, but the standard does not require it ([demo](http://ideone.com/CRGYSD)).

Comment: thanks, so the compiler can upcast but cannot downcast? so if I pass double to a function which requires int,  will I get an error? I guess I can just try this:)

Comment: @Mcs The compiler will do it both ways, assuming that the function has a proper prototype.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler to be able to pass the correct arguments to a function, it needs to be told what types the function expects. This means that you have to provide a full declaration of the function, and it can be done in two ways.

In the case of `sqrt()` you would typically `#include <math.h>`. The other way is to declare the function explicitly in your source code: `double sqrt (double);`.

Once the compiler knows what types the function expected and returns, it will, if possible, convert the arguments to the correct types. `int` and `double` can be converted implicitly.

If you fail to declare the types of the parameters for the function, the *default argument promotions* will be applied to the arguments, which means small integer types will be converted to `int`, and `float` will be converted to `double`. Your  `int` argument will be blindly passed as an `int` using some implementation-specific method, while the `sqrt()` function will retrieve its parameter as a `double` using some other implementation-specific method. This will, obviously, not work properly if the two methods differ, which is why passing the wrong types to a function without a full declaration results in *undefined behaviour*.

In the last two versions of the C standard, you are not allowed to call a function without a prior declaration, and the compiler is required to emit a diagnostic message. However, for historical reasons, this declaration is not required to provide the types of the parameters.